# Where exactly to add serialize hook (emberJS)

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have been following the EmberJS tutorial at tutorialspoint.com, and was going through the "**routes**" section, when I came across [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/emberjs/router_dynamic_segment.htm) page. It explains how to use dynamic segments in ember. So far I understand the code on how the route.js is updated and how the hbs file is created etc. (that's all pretty straightforward). What I don't understand is the last part where a serialize hook is made. I understand the code, but don't exactly know in which file should I put it? There is no mention of it in the tutorial, and I searched stackoverflow as well but the only answer relevant to this was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402495/use-of-serialize-hook-in-ember-routes) where it explains how they work rather than where to add them. Can someone please explain in which file should I add this code? Thanks.

Comment: In the route as its shown in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [emberjs api](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/Route/methods/serialize?anchor=serialize). serialize(model) is a method of class Route. Usually you don't have to implement the method, because the default implementation should suffice in the majority of cases. The default implementation adds the model's ID as the dynamic segment of the defined route.

```
//router
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('user', { path: '/user/:user_id' }); //user_id is the dynamic segment
});


//route with default serialize implementation
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
export default Route.extend({
  model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('user', params.user_id);
  }
});
```